# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name not working in HIVE in RHEL 6

Tags: postgresql, hive

When I am trying to run select query in hive, it stops after these three steps:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name; 

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
```

After this nothing works and I have to kill hive and then restart it but when I am using:

```
SELECT * from table_name
```

with `WHERE` condition it works fine.

I have looked into different answers but not getting any particular explanation on this.

Can anyone suggest an explanation for this?

I am also facing another issue with the same query and that is

> Total MapReduce jobs = 1
>  Launching Job 1 out of 1
>  Number of
>   reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
>  In order to change the
>   average load for a reducer (in bytes):
>    **set
>   hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=number**
>  In order to limit
>   the maximum number of reducers:
>    **set
>   hive.exec.reducers.max=number**
>  In order to set a constant number of reducers:
> **set mapred.reduce.tasks=number**
>   Interrupting... Be patient, this might take some time.

Where these fields need to be set and what should be the default values?

Thanks, Soham

Comment: Finally got it worked. Basically my application was using all the ports which yarn needs to start.